# Android LibGDX Particle System is fixed on screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, particle-system

I have a 3D scene that runs on libGDX(Android). I want to use particle system. When I create one using the tutorials/examples found online (e.g. [Particle System libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569878/particle-system-libgdx/9573836#9573836)) I get a particle system which works fine. Except for one thing: it is fixed on screen.

When I move the camera around the particle system stays on the same place on screen (like a fixed HUD element or so). Maybe it's because of Sprite-nature of `ParticleEffect`.

The other issue related is that the `ParticleEffect.setPosition()` method takes values not in the World coordinates but in screen pixels. Is this correct? I can calculate new on-screen coordinates in pixels and update `ParticleEffect` position every frame. But that seems like a hack to me.

Is there a more "*right*" way to make my particle system behave like other objects in my 3D scene and not be fixed on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Particle System is just working in 2D System. It's not a 3D Particle System thats why you wont get it into your world. That's why it's inside of the `g2d` package (graphics 2D). Thats also the reason why it just take 2D cords and not 3D cords.

Also the Feature list says that it's inside of the 2D Highlevel API.

[Featurelist](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html)

Comment: I understand that it is a 2D enity. But this doesn't explain why it's fixed to camera. From my understanding 2D scene also has world coordinates and not always fits the screen so camera pans are possible. And particles system that stays on same place on screen is not very useful in that case